# NUnit C# test return

Tags: c#, nunit

**nUnit**

**Есть метод void Validate(XXX model)**
В котором есть такая проверка

```
if (model.Name == null) return;
```

Пробовал `Assert.Throws<Exception>, Assert.IsNul, Assert.Null, Assert.IsNotNull`
Но всё на основе `Assert.Throws<Exception>` по этому он возвращает null и тест ругается на то что ожидает Exception а, получает null, что вообщем то логично!!!

Как проверить этот return???

Comment: Вот именно поэтому тесты хороши не только с точки зрения проверки кода, они "заставляют" писать правильно с точки зрения архитектуры. Метод `Validate` по-идее, не должен возвращать `void`, а должен  `bool`, ну или в классе должно быть свойство `HasValidated`, которое и нужно проверять после отработки вашего `void Validate(XXX model)`.

Comment: @Bulson Можно и так, но метод я менять не могу, нужно проверить именно void/return;

Comment: `...проверить именно void/return` невозможно также как и пустоту. Проверка осуществляется на данных: есть/нет или соответствует значение/величина заданному.

Comment: Или выбрасывайте исключение вместо простого `return;`

Comment: @Bulson Я думал, может есть способ в тесте указать что метод сделал return;!